# Convert a Word Multilevel list to an indented list

Tags: ms-word

Is there an easy way to convert a Word multilevel list to a tab (or space) indented list? I'm trying to take a list from Word and convert it to a multilevel array in PHP:

I'd like to convert:

```
I ...
 A ...
  1 ...
  2 ...
 B ...
  1 ...
   a ...
   b ...
II ...
```

into

```
...
 ...
  ...
  ...
 ...
  ...
   ...
   ...
 ...
```

Copying and pasting unformatted text does not give any indenting. i.e :

```
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
```